Number of force_merge threads
I have opensearch “2.11.0” and I can’t increase the number of force_merge threads.
GET /_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true says :
    "thread_pool": {
.......,
      "force_merge": {
        "queue_size": "-1",
        "size": "3"
      },

but despite that GET /_cat/thread_pool says:
node1 force_merge                                 1 0 0
node2 force_merge                                 1 0 0

and force_merge takes too long
Index that’s merging also has increased config:
GET /index123/_settings :
"merge": {
  "scheduler": {
    "max_thread_count": "43",
    "max_merge_count": "50"
  },
  "policy": {
    "floor_segment": "100mb",
    "max_merge_at_once": "40",
    "max_merged_segment": "2gb"
  }
},

Why there are only 2 forcemerge threads instead of 2*3=6 ?

What do you see when you run GET /_cat/thread_pool?h=nn,psz? The default GET /_cat/thread_pool command only shows the currently active threads (i.e. 1 in your case), if you want to see the number of threads, you need to check the psz column

When I do GET /_cat/thread_pool/force_merge?h=node_name,name,psz,a,q,r  I see:
node1 force_merge 3 1 0 0
node2 force_merge 3 1 0 0
Total 3 threads and only 1active - why?

It depends on the forcemerge command you ran. Can you elaborate a bit on what you're running? We see 3 threads per node, which is consistent with the thread_pool.force_merge.size cluster setting you shared (and is based on the number of CPUs you have, also stored in the node.processors setting)

I run /index123/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=12 on cluster with 2nodes.
Each node has :    "available_processors": 64,  "allocated_processors": 64
I don't set node.processors explicitly

What do you get when running GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true&filter_path=**.node.processors?

"processors": "64", but I perhaps understand this problem. It appears for each node, the index can have only one forcemerge thread. Now I have run forcemerge for two indexes at once, and now I have: node1 force_merge 3 2 0 0 node2 force_merge 3 2 0 0

Indeed, force merge only runs a single thread per index, otherwise havoc could happen :-)
